# .toList() return an exception

Tags: mysql, entity-framework, asp.net-web-api, linq-to-entities

I have this method that run against MySQL database the result is an exception with all the code bellow.

Then tried the query with take(10) method and it works fine but could not figure out why yet.

The table that I'm iterating over has a millions of rows.
can someone explain whats happening and why ? 
Thanks

```
public IHttpActionResult retentionRate() {   
        DateTime today = DateTime.Today;
        DateTime firstOfThisMonth = new DateTime(today.Year, today.Month, 1);
        DateTime  LastYearDate = DateTime.Today.AddDays(-365);

            var activeInDateRange = (from mp in FitnessDbo.memberproductinfoes
                                     where mp.mepi_expirydate >= LastYearDate &&
                                     mp.mepi_activationdate < today
                                     select new
                                     {
                                         mepi_memberproductinfoid = mp.mepi_memberproductinfoid,
                                         mepi_memberid = mp.mepi_memberid,
                                         mepi_activationdate = (mp.mepi_activationdate < LastYearDate ? LastYearDate : mp.mepi_activationdate),
                                         mepi_expirydate = (mp.mepi_expirydate > today ? today : mp.mepi_expirydate),
                                         mepi_prodtype = mp.mepi_prodtype,
                                         mepi_producttypeinfo = mp.mepi_producttypeinfo,
                                         mepi_memberproducttype = mp.mepi_memberproducttype,
                                         mepi_status = mp.mepi_status
                                     }).ToList();

        return Ok(activeInDateRange);
    }
```

With Take() method:

```
public IHttpActionResult retentionRate() {

        DateTime today = DateTime.Today;
        DateTime firstOfThisMonth = new DateTime(today.Year, today.Month, 1);
        DateTime  LastYearDate = DateTime.Today.AddDays(-365);




           var activeInDateRange = (from mp in FitnessDbo.memberproductinfoes
                                     where mp.mepi_expirydate >= LastYearDate &&
                                     mp.mepi_activationdate < today
                                     select new
                                     {
                                         mepi_memberproductinfoid = mp.mepi_memberproductinfoid,
                                         mepi_memberid = mp.mepi_memberid,
                                         mepi_activationdate = (mp.mepi_activationdate < LastYearDate ? LastYearDate : mp.mepi_activationdate),
                                         mepi_expirydate = (mp.mepi_expirydate.Value > today? today : mp.mepi_expirydate),
                                         mepi_prodtype = mp.mepi_prodtype,
                                         mepi_producttypeinfo = mp.mepi_producttypeinfo,
                                         mepi_memberproducttype = mp.mepi_memberproducttype,
                                         mepi_status = mp.mepi_status
                                     }).Take(10);
}
```

Exception I have Received

```
{"message":"An error has occurred.",
"exceptionMessage":"Calling 'Read' when the data reader is closed is not a valid operation.",
"exceptionType":"System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityCommandExecutionException",
"stackTrace":
   "   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Common.Internal.Materialization.Shaper\`1.HandleReaderException(Exception e)\r\n
       at System.Data.Entity.Core.Common.Internal.Materialization.Shaper\`1.StoreRead()\r\n   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Common.Internal.Materialization.Shaper\`1.SimpleEnumerator.MoveNext()\r\n
       at System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyEnumerator\`1.MoveNext()\r\n
       at System.Collections.Generic.List\`1..ctor(IEnumerable\`1 collection)\r\n
       at System.Linq.Enumerable.ToList[TSource](IEnumerable\`1 source)\r\n
       at BI_leejam.Controllers.MembersController.retentionRate() in C:\\Users\\ahijazi\\source\\repos\\BI_leejam\\BI_leejam\\Controllers\\MembersController.cs:line 123\r\n
       at lambda_method(Closure , Object , Object[] )\r\n
       at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ReflectedHttpActionDescriptor.ActionExecutor.<>c__DisplayClass6_2.<GetExecutor>b__2(Object instance, Object[] methodParameters)\r\n
       at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ReflectedHttpActionDescriptor.ActionExecutor.Execute(Object instance, Object[] arguments)\r\n
       at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ReflectedHttpActionDescriptor.ExecuteAsync(HttpControllerContext controllerContext, IDictionary\`2 arguments, CancellationToken cancellationToken)\r\n
    --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n
       at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)\r\n
       at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n
       at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ApiControllerActionInvoker.<InvokeActionAsyncCore>d__1.MoveNext()\r\n
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n
       at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)\r\n
       at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n
       at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ActionFilterResult.<ExecuteAsync>d__5.MoveNext()\r\n
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n
       at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)\r\n
       at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n
       at System.Web.Http.Dispatcher.HttpControllerDispatcher.<SendAsync>d__15.MoveNext()",
"innerException":{"message":"An error has occurred.",
    "exceptionMessage":"Timeout expired.  The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the operation or the server is not responding.",
    "exceptionType":"MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException",
    "stackTrace":
       "   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.Interceptors.ExceptionInterceptor.Throw(Exception exception)\r\n
           at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection.Throw(Exception ex)\r\n   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection.HandleTimeoutOrThreadAbort(Exception ex)\r\n
           at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlDataReader.Read()\r\n
           at MySql.Data.EntityFramework.EFMySqlDataReader.Read()\r\n
           at System.Data.Entity.Core.Common.Internal.Materialization.Shaper\`1.StoreRead()",
    "innerException":{"message":"An error has occurred.",
        "exceptionMessage":"Timeout in IO operation",
        "exceptionType":"System.TimeoutException",
        "stackTrace":
       "   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.TimedStream.StopTimer()\r\n
           at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.TimedStream.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count)\r\n
           at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlStream.ReadFully(Stream stream, Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count)\r\n
           at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlStream.LoadPacket()\r\n
           at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlStream.ReadPacket()\r\n
           at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.NativeDriver.FetchDataRow(Int32 statementId, Int32 columns)\r\n
           at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.Driver.FetchDataRow(Int32 statementId, Int32 columns)\r\n
           at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.ResultSet.GetNextRow()\r\n
           at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.ResultSet.NextRow(CommandBehavior behavior)\r\n
           at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlDataReader.Read()"}}}
```

Comment: First I would isolate the query from the where operators. It might be that the "LastYearDate" and "today" might not work within a Linq -> SQL query. 

Also where are you putting the .Take(10)? Could you add that to your question.

Comment: From the error I would not say that the issue is with using `.ToList()`. It sounds like the connection has closed. If it works requesting 10 rows, then does the table contain millions of rows that might cause a query timeout? What happens if you write and execute an equivalent query using database tools rather than code?

Comment: @JARRRRG isolate? which means to calculate before the query is build or what ? i have added the code with take() method.

Comment: @CraigH the equivalent query works well with about 3 seconds of execution time in average and yes the table does have a million of rows.

Comment: @user12137978 3 seconds to return 10 rows, or all of them?

Comment: @CraigH Yes Everything and not only 10 rows.

Comment: Hmm. It looks from your code that you have a DB context as a property on the controller? What happens if you create a new context just for that call? e.g. `using(FitnessDbo fdb = new FitnessDbo()) { var activeInDateRange = (from mp in fdb.memberproductinfoes ...` ?

Comment: Although the error is all about timeouts - so it's probably worth looking to see if you can increase the timeout period through the connection string.

Comment: @CraigH i have done that using this "FitnessDbo.Database.CommandTimeout = 300; "line of code and still not working

Comment: @CraigH i have used  using(dbcontext) and dbContext.Database.CommandTimeout = 300 within it and it works now but can you explain why  and why this all amount of time for kinda query that takes 3 seconds on direct SQl query? please.

Comment: It could be a number of things. Is the context given to the controller through dependency injection? If so, what is the lifetime of the context in the DI container?

Comment: @CraigH the context is identified as a private property in my controller and from their I'm call it so no dependency injection at all. if there is something wrong with my approach please recommend me something to read to understand the best about it. appreciate every single letter you have typed back helping me out. Thanks

Comment: I have tended to instantiate new db contexts inside a using statement every time I need to use one, so it is created, used, and then properly disposed of. This doesn't always make sense to do though if you want the data to be "cached" in the context for later use. Although your controller handles the request and is then disposed, perhaps the application tries to be clever and reuse the context, and then the connection has already been closed by the previous use. Do you find that the first call works, and then the next doesn't?

Comment: @CraigH yes this is happened to me first time i called the query, it worked and after that it was  into this exception with no clue why. With your approach for trying using() , it worked and then i have built another query on the old query i have posted here and a dispose exception appeared too. I think it's not my day today but i have learnt a lot.

Comment: Revert back to your original setup, and see my answer below... It was easier to add it as an answer than to try and include it in comments!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding this to your controller:

```
protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
{
    if (disposing)
    {
        if (this.FitnessDbo != null) { this.FitnessDbo.Dispose(); }
    }

    base.Dispose(disposing);
}
```

Edit for some explanation:
From the questions via comments, it sounds like even though the controller is disposed at the end of a request, the connections used by the context are being reused but are not in a useable state. By explicitly disposing of the context when the controller is disposed, the context and connections should be closed properly ensuring we get a fresh connection on the next request.